# Why does @SpringBootTest run the @SpringBootApplication and skip the @Test method?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-test

I created an integration test for a SpringBoot command line application following step 7 in this [example](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-testing):

Here's my integration test

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:application.integrationtest.properties")
public class IntegrationTest {

    @Autowired
    private RequestProcessor requestProcessor;


    @Test
    public void testRequestProcessor() {
        requestProcessor.setStandloneFlag(true);
        requestProcessor.processRequest();

    }
}
```

When I run this test it launches the @SpringBootApplication itself, but never runs the @Test method in the integration test.  The [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html) say that this should not happen.

Why does @SpringBootTest ignore my @Test method and launch the application?

Comment: Then there must be something in your code preventing it from being called. Also how do you now that the `@Test` method is ignored? (Did you use the correct `@Test` annotation?).

Comment: I know it is being ignored by setting a breakpoint there and in the run() method of the SpringBootApplication class.  The debugger breaks in the run() method but never in the @Test method.

I'm using the org.junit.Test annotation from junit 4.12.

Comment: Does it actually finish without running the test or the whole things waits?

Comment: It never runs the Test.  The application itself runs continuously, so if SpringBootTest is waiting for the app to terminate that will never happen.  There is a parameter to tell the app to terminate when it has processed all files available.  I set that parameter in the Test method but not when running the app itself.

Comment: Do you do some blocking stuff when starting the application? That might prevent the actual test from being executed due to the main thread being too busy.